# How to put TEdit data into String C++ Builder

Tags: c++builder, c++builder-xe7

I am new in programming. Actually I am in 2nd year of college and  starting an internship. They want me to do a program in C++ builder but I only know C. What I studied. And I don't have any knowledge about OOP.

So my question is.

I have TEdit1 and I want to verify if the data introduced in that textbox is a number. I know to verify if it is a number but I don't know how to put data from TEdit into string.

I wrote some code but it doesn't work.

```
void __fastcall TForm1::Button1Click(TObject *Sender) 
{
    int Size = Edit1->GetTextLen(); //Get length of string in Edit1
    Size++;                         //Add room for null character
    Char *Buffer = new Char[Size];  //Creates Buffer dynamic variable

    std::auto_ptr<Char> Buffer(new Char[Size]);

    Edit1->GetTextBuf(Buffer.get(),Size); //Puts Edit1->Text into Buffer

    ShowMessage(Buffer);
}
```

And I get these errors:

```
 E2034 Cannot convert 'std::auto_ptr<wchar_t>' to 'UnicodeString'
 E2342 Type mismatch in parameter 'Msg' (wanted 'const UnicodeString', got              std::auto_ptr<wchar_t>')
```

Can you please explain what i did wrong, or where i can found Embarcadero C++ Builder tutorials? I searched all google and didn't find something to help me.

Answer (score 2):

Your code has several mistakes in it:

1. you are declaring two `Buffer` variables in the same scope.  That is not allowed.  You need to remove one of them.
2. you are passing the [`std::auto_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/auto_ptr) itself to `ShowMessage()`, but it expects a [`System::UnicodeString`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/System.UnicodeString) instead, thus the compiler error message.  You can use the `std::auto_ptr::get()` method to get the `wchar_t*` pointer and pass it to `ShowMessage()`, as `UnicodeString` has a constructor that accepts `wchar_t*` as input:

   ```
   ShowMessage(Buffer.get());
   ```
3. despite the above, you actually cannot use a pointer from `new[]` with `std::auto_ptr` to begin with.  `std::auto_ptr` uses `delete` instead of `delete[]` to free the memory being pointed at.  You must always use `delete` with `new`, and `delete[]` with `new[]`.  So, while the code will compile, it will not free the memory correctly at runtime.  C++11 introduced a new [`std::unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) class to replace `std::auto_ptr`, and `std::unique_ptr` supports `new[]` and `delete[]` (however, C++Builder's 32bit compiler does not support C++11 yet - that is in the works - but its 64bit compiler does):

   ```
   #include <memory>

   void __fastcall TForm1::Button1Click(TObject *Sender) 
   {
       int Size = Edit1->GetTextLen(); //Get length of string in Edit1
       Size++;                         //Add room for null character

       std::unique_ptr<Char[]> Buffer(new Char[Size]); //Creates Buffer dynamic variable

       Edit1->GetTextBuf(Buffer.get(), Size); //Puts Edit1->Text into Buffer

       ShowMessage(Buffer.get());
   }
   ```

Now, with that said, if you are going to continue using C++Builder, you should learn how to use its built-in functionalities, like `UnicodeString`, which the RTL/VCL relies heavily on (use the `System::String` alias for most code, use `UnicodeString` directly only when absolutely necessary).

Your example can be vastly simplified using the [`TEdit::Text`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/Vcl.StdCtrls.TEdit.Text) property:

```
void __fastcall TForm1::Button1Click(TObject *Sender) 
{
    String s = Edit1->Text; //Get string in Edit1
    ShowMessage(s);
}
```

The simplest solution to your problem would be to use the `TCSpinEdit` component instead of `TEdit`, as `TCSpinEdit` only allows numeric input in the first place, and has a `Value` property that returns an `int`:

```
void __fastcall TForm1::Button1Click(TObject *Sender) 
{
    int number = CSpinEdit1->Value;
    ShowMessage("It is a number");
    // use number as needed...
}
```

But, if you have to stick with `TEdit`, there are many ways to check a `UnicodeString` for numeric content.

You can set the [`TEdit::NumbersOnly`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/Vcl.StdCtrls.TEdit.NumbersOnly) property to true so the user cannot enter a non-numeric value (unless they use copy/paste, but let's ignore that for the moment), and then use the RTL's [`StrToInt()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/System.SysUtils.StrToInt) function, or [`System::UnicodeString::ToInt()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/System.UnicodeString.ToInt) method, to convert it as-is:

```
#include <System.SysUtils.hpp>

void __fastcall TForm1::Button1Click(TObject *Sender) 
{
    int number;

    try
    {
        number = StrToInt(Edit1->Text);
        // or: number = Edit1->Text.ToInt();
    }
    catch (const EConvertError&)
    {
        // not a number, do something else...
        ShowMessage("It is not a number");
        return;
    }

    ShowMessage("It is a number");
    // use number as needed...
}
```

Or you can use the RTL's [`System::Sysutils::TryStrToInt()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/System.SysUtils.TryStrToInt) function:

```
#include <System.SysUtils.hpp>

void __fastcall TForm1::Button1Click(TObject *Sender) 
{
    int number;

    if (TryStrToInt(Edit1->Text, number))
    {
        // use number as needed...
        ShowMessage("It is a number");
    }
    else
    {
        // not a number, do something else...
        ShowMessage("It is not a number");
    }
}
```

Or you can use the STL's [`std::wistringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream) class:

```
#include <sstream>

void __fastcall TForm1::Button1Click(TObject *Sender) 
{
    int number;

    std::wistringstream iss(Edit1->Text.c_str());
    if (iss >> number)
    {
        // use number as needed...
        ShowMessage("It is a number");
    }
    else
    {
        // not a number, do something else...
        ShowMessage("It is not a number");
    }
}
```

Or, since you have a C background, you can use the C [`_wtoi()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/atoi) function (which doesn't offer much in the way of error checking):

```
#include <cstdlib>

void __fastcall TForm1::Button1Click(TObject *Sender) 
{
    int number = std::_wtoi(Edit1->Text.c_str());
    if (number != 0)
    {
        // use number as needed...
        ShowMessage("It is a valid number");
    }
    else
    {
        // not a number, do something else...
        ShowMessage("It is not a valid number");
    }
}
```

Or you can use the C [`wcstol()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/wide/wcstol) function:

```
#include <cstdlib>

void __fastcall TForm1::Button1Click(TObject *Sender) 
{
    String s = Edit1->Text;
    Char *p = s.c_str(), *end;
    int number = std::wcstol(p, &end, 10);
    if (end != p)
    {
        // use number as needed...
        ShowMessage("It is a number");
    }
    else
    {
        // not a number, do something else...
        ShowMessage("It is not a number");
    }
}
```

Or you can use the C [`swscanf()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fwscanf) function:

```
#include <cstdio>

void __fastcall TForm1::Button1Click(TObject *Sender) 
{
    int number;

    if (std::swscanf(Edit1->Text.c_str(), L"%d", &number) == 1)
    {
        // use number as needed...
        ShowMessage("It is a number");
    }
    else
    {
        // not a number, do something else...
        ShowMessage("It is not a number");
    }
}
```

Comment: XE5's bcc32 has `std::unique_ptr`. It's not quite compliant (it requires its template parameter to be a complete type in some situations where C++11 allows an incomplete type) but it's good enough for many uses, including pImpls

Comment: `ShowMessage( Edit1->Text );` would be another option

Comment: @MattMcNabb: sure, that would address the specific example Cantor gave, but not the overall task Cantor is trying to solve.